# Python - Selenium - Problems navigating in iframes

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I've been trying to log into a website using selenium. I have the following problem > i manage to open an iframe (it is correctly displayed after i click on the login button) but i've been unable to move into it. I've been trying to find it via it's Id and name but i somehow can't find it...

The line looks like:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("frameid"))
```

I get an error "no such element". I checked 1000 times the id and it is correct! The frame i want to switch to is not inside another frame.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you share a link to the website you are working with?

Comment: I prefer not to but i'm gonna reproduce the code >

Answer (score 0):

> It seem's that the id is somehow dynamically allocated but always starts with the same characters. I can't use a regex-based search apparently

In this case you can locate it with an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) function:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'something')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Or, with a [CSS "begin with" selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id^=something]")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```